# Power of a Jeffreys test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

The Jeffrey test is a tool used to evaluate evaluation of proportions, notably in the IRB Framework to evaluate the probability of default (see: [ECB - Instructions for reporting the validation results of internal models](https://www.bankingsupervision.europa.eu/banking/tasks/internal_models/shared/pdf/instructions_validation_reporting_credit_risk.en.pdf) art 2.5.3.1).

This paper on [Proving Prediction Prudence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.03698.pdf) formulate the hypothese testing further:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a notion / an analytical formula for the power for such a test, notably given the prior distribution, where the Power would be:

$$ Power = P ({reject\ H0}| H1\ is\ True)$$

Comment: The term "$H_1$ is true" is a bit ambiguous. Multiple values of $\vartheta$ correspond to $H_1$ being true, and for each specific value the power is different. How do you wish to consider them? Weighing them based on the prior? For that case you could use a Monte Carlo approach by sampling the prior and simulate a test, then compute the probability of rejection conditional on the alternative hypothesis being true

Comment: I am  not sure about the options and what is at stake... but I need to start somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example, say we consider

- a parameter $\theta$ for some binomial proportion
- a test with a sample size of $n=200$, and we denote the observed value as $k$.
- use of the Jeffreys prior which is a beta distribution, $\theta_{prior} \sim Beta(0.5,0.5)$. And the posterior distribution will be a beta distribution as well, $\theta_{posterior} \sim Beta(0.5+k,0.5+n-k)$
- A composite null hypothesis $H_0: \theta \leq \theta_{applied}$ and alternative $H_a: \theta > \theta_{applied}$. In the example below we use $\theta_{applied} = 0.1$
- The Jeffreys test will consider the rejection of the null hypothesis when the posterior probability is below some level, $P_{posterior}(H_0) < \alpha$. Say we use $\alpha = 0.05$.

Then we can express the probability $P_{posterior}(H_0)$ as function of the observed $k$.

[image: probability of H_0 as function of k]

The observations with $k \geq 28$ correspond to cases where $P(H_0) \leq 0.05$ and will lead to a rejection of the null hypothesis.

The power is the probability that this happens. How likely this will happen depends on the actual value of $\theta$. The higher the value, the more likely that we will observe $k \geq 28$ and reject the null hypothesis.

[image: power as function of true theta]

In the question it is not about the power as function of $\theta$ but as function of the alternative being true. One way to express this is as the prior probability of rejecting the null hypothesis, with the condition that the null hypothesis is true. For this we can integrate $$P_{prior}(\text{reject $|H_a$ true}) = \frac{\int_{\theta_{applied}}^1 f_{{prior}}(\theta) p_{reject}(\theta) \, \text{d} \theta} {\int_{\theta_{applied}}^1 f_{{prior}}(\theta)  \, \text{d} \theta} $$

See for the prior density $f_{prior}(\theta)$ the function in the figure below. Here we also added colors. Blue for the cases where the null hypothesis is true, red for the cases where the alternative hypothesis is true.

[image: prior distribution for theta]

With the given case $n=200$, $\theta_{applied} = 0.1$ and $\alpha = 0.05$ we have a power of approximately

$$P_{prior}(\text{reject $|H_a$ true}) \approx 0.9515638$$

we did the same approach to compute the type I error rate (probability to reject the null hypothesis conditional on the null hypothesis being true) and this is approximately

$$P_{prior}(\text{reject $|H_0$ true}) \approx 0.002027451$$

it is different from $\alpha = 0.05$ because the null hypothesis also relates to cases $\theta << \theta_{applied}$ and in addition the rejection criterion of the posterior probability is not the same as a a p-value.

As a bonus we computed the power and type I error rate for different sample sizes

[image: power and type I error as function of sample size]

The code below is used to create the graphs above and may help as an extra explanation of the approach

```r
n_sample = 200
applied = 0.1
alpha = 0.05

### compute posterior probability for H_0 as function of observations 
observed = 1:n_sample
p_value = pbeta(applied,0.5+observed,0.5+n_sample-observed)

### plot the posterior probability
### color cases with p<0.05 which lead to rejection of H_0
plot(observed, p_value, 
     main = "posterior probability of H_0: true theta below applied 0.1 \n sample size 200",
     xlab = "observed cases", 
     pch = 20, cex = 0.5, col = 1+(p_value < alpha)) 

### get the cutoff value for the test
### with the observation above which 
### the test leads to rejection 
cutoff = observed[min(which(p_value < alpha))]


### compute for hypothetical values the probability
### of an observation that leads to rejection 
dt = 0.001
theta = seq(dt,1-dt,dt)+dt/2
p_reject = 1-pbinom(cutoff-1, n_sample, theta)
plot(theta, p_reject, 
     xlab = "true theta",
     ylab = "reject probability",
     main = "power as function of true theta", 
     pch = 20, cex = 0.5)



### prior distribution of theta
plot(theta, dbeta(theta,0.5,0.5), 
     xlab = "theta",
     ylab = "prior probability",
     main = "prior probability density of theta", 
     pch = 20, cex = 0.5, 
     col = 2+2*(theta <= applied))
text(applied/2,6,"H_0 true", col = 4, pos = 4)
text((1+applied)/2,6,"H_a true", col = 2)

### compute based on integrating above graphs
### the probability of rejection
### conditional on theta being below or above applied
dtheta = dbeta(theta,0.5,0.5)
sel_ha = which(theta > applied)
sel_h0 = which(theta <= applied)
power = sum(dtheta[sel_ha]*p_reject[sel_ha])/ sum(dtheta[sel_ha])
typeI_error = sum(dtheta[sel_h0]*p_reject[sel_h0])/ sum(dtheta[sel_h0])

power        # 0.9515638 
typeI_error  # 0.002027451



### the above as a function of the sample size

power_error = function(n_sample, alpha = 0.05, applied = 0.1) {
  observed = 1:n_sample
  p_value = pbeta(applied,0.5+observed,0.5+n_sample-observed)

  cutoff = observed[min(which(p_value < alpha))]

  dt = 0.001
theta = seq(dt,1-dt,dt)+dt/2
p_reject = 1-pbinom(cutoff-1, n_sample, theta)


  dtheta = dbeta(theta,0.5,0.5)
  sel_ha = which(theta > applied)
  sel_h0 = which(theta <= applied)

  power = sum(dtheta[sel_ha]*p_reject[sel_ha])/ sum(dtheta[sel_ha])

  typeI_error = sum(dtheta[sel_h0]*p_reject[sel_h0])/ sum(dtheta[sel_h0])

  return(c(power,typeI_error))
}


sample = seq(10,2000,10)
out = sapply(sample, FUN = function(k) {
   power_error(k)
})

plot(sample,out[1,], 
     xlab = "sample size",
     ylab = "power")
plot(sample,out[2,], 
     xlab = "sample size",
     ylab = "type I error rate")
```